# VSTGUI 4.0.1 XCODE 4.5 and MacOSX 10.8 Troubles

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, vst

That's the first time I use stack overflow 'cause I got a problem develop VST Plugins with GUI on MacOSX 10.8. 
I'm new to mac development and I'm not shure why I get the following errors due compiling and linking my product using VSTGUI 4.0.1.

```
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/aeffguieditor.cpp:115:34: 'createDrawContext' is deprecated
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/aeffguieditor.cpp:182:10: 'TickCount' is deprecated: first deprecated in Mac OS X 10.8
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/aeffguieditor.cpp:237:27: Conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/cview.cpp
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/cview.cpp:661:22: No matching function for call to 'make_pair'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/macfileselector.mm
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/macfileselector.mm:239:5: 'beginSheetForDirectory:file:types:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:' is deprecated
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/macfileselector.mm:244:21: 'runModalForDirectory:file:types:' is deprecated
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/macfileselector.mm:255:5: 'beginSheetForDirectory:file:modalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:' is deprecated
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/macfileselector.mm:260:21: 'runModalForDirectory:file:' is deprecated
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:493:4: Use of undeclared identifier 'GetPortBounds'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:524:2: Use of undeclared identifier 'GetPortBounds'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:539:24: Use of undeclared identifier 'QDSwapPort'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:542:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'QDSwapPort'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:634:124: Non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'CCoord' (aka 'double') to 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') in initializer list
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:747:13: Enumeration value 'kError' not handled in switch
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:808:24: Use of undeclared identifier 'NewRgn'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:822:5: Use of undeclared identifier 'DisposeRgn'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:1016:17: Use of undeclared identifier 'kQDRegionToRectsMsgParse'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewframe.cpp:1117:37: Use of undeclared identifier 'kQDParseRegionFromTopLeft'
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewoptionmenu.cpp
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewoptionmenu.cpp:107:17: 'UniqueID' is deprecated: first deprecated in Mac OS X 10.8
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewtextedit.cpp
/Users/christianschragen/Downloads/samples/vst2.x/mac/lib/platform/mac/carbon/hiviewtextedit.cpp:111:3: Use of undeclared identifier 'GetFNum'
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a strong feeling that VSTGUI does not support 10.8 yet. You should set the target SDK in your Xcode build settings to 10.7 (or maybe 10.6), which probably involves downloading a huge DMG from Apple via Xcode.

Also it probably wouldn't hurt to contact the VSTGUI developers to seek support from them.

Comment: hey, thanks. I solved it for now. Downloaded the SDKs from 10.4 to 10.6 and using the vst sdk 2.4 template for now. it works.
I'm very new to Xcode and Mac/Unix. I'll have to try and error ;)

Comment: I have one math question, if you could help me one more time.
In my source I am trying to make stere expansion with pan control.
But it seems that I loose some gain. Can this happen in the panorama code with sqrt()?

   /* //Code
    (*out1++) = (mid+side) * fGain * sqrt(fOne - fPan);
    (*out2++) = (mid-side) * fGain * sqrt(fPan);
*/

Comment: Cool, don't forget to mark the question as answered to help others who wind up here via google. :) As for the other question, can you make a new question for it? I'm not sure that I know the answer, but someone else on SO might.